# Ruby rspec error for pushing into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec

Im trying to pass a test for pushing an item into an array from another class.
Here is the method.

```
require_relative 'message'

class Test

  attr_reader :message

  def initialize(message = Message.new)
    @message = message
  end

  def push(hello)
    @message.array << hello
  end
end
```

The empty array in a different class.

```
class Message

  attr_reader :array 

  def initialize
    @array = []
  end
end
```

and my test.

```
require 'test'

describe Test do

  let(:message) { double(array: [])}

  describe '#push' do
    it 'pushes an item into an array from the message class' do
      subject.push("hello")
      expect(message.array).to eq ["hello"]
    end
  end
end
```

currenty getting the error

```
expected: ["hello"]
     got: []

       (compared using ==)
```

what am i doing wrong? The method itself is simple and works, why does my test not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message` you defined here : `let(:message) { double(array: [])}` has nothing to do with the rest.

Since you pushed into `subject` you have to check on it.

```rb
require 'test'

describe Test do
  describe '#push' do
    it 'pushes an item into an array from the message class' do
      subject = Test.new
      subject.push("hello")
      expect(subject.message.array).to eq ["hello"]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ahhhhh can't belive i missed that! thanks so much dude ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) (Don't hesitate to flag it as the good answer if it solved your problem)

Answer (score 0):

In your let, you assign an empty array to message and then test if it contains 'hello'. That fails because message is empty. Did you mean to push 'hello' to the message array instead of to 'subject'?